# Invitation token not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Suddenly the invitation tokens of Devise invitable are not valid anymore.
I am sending emails containing a link link this:

```
<url>/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=Yr4PWJQNTTu1xP8sU5q5
```

The link in the email view is like this:

```
= link_to "accept invitation", accept_invitation_url(@user, :invitation_token => @user.invitation_token)
```

But I see this error:

```
The invitation token provided is not valid!
```

What is going wrong here? It worked until recently and to my knowledge nothing has changed in this area.

Edit: when using `:invitation_token => @token` or `:invitation_token => @user.raw_invitation_token`, it shows an URL without invitation_token in the email:

```
<url>/users/invitation/accept
```

I'm using:

```
devise (3.5.2)
devise_invitable (1.5.5)
```

Comment: In which environment you are facing the issue?

Comment: Production. On Development the token is OK.

Comment: Hmm. We once had the same issue on development and the problem is the port number which is set in `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` is not the same as the server which we are running. May be try looking the same in your case

Comment: There is only the URL but not a port, like `https://www.bla.com`

Comment: I am incorrect, it also doesn't work on development :-(